# Browse files to open and run using GUI python

Tags: python

Hi i have some python scripts. I need to create a GUI with few buttons, to open those files by browsing. I have to run those scripts just by clicking the GUI button, and should write the output into a n excel sheet. I tried with the below code, but with that i can just read the file! please help?
Thank you

```
from Tkinter import *            
from tkFileDialog   
import askopenfilename      

def callback():
    r = open(askopenfilename(),'r')

a = Button(text='click me', command=callback)
a.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Bind an action to the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside the callback() instead of opening the file, execute the file using execfile("abc.py")

```
def callback():
    abc = askopenfilename()
    execfile("abc.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below is a simple example that reads each line from the selected input file and then writes it to a new excel file called output.xls. It use the excellent [xlwt library](http://www.python-excel.org/) for creating the excel file. You could also chose to create a csv file using the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module that is part of the python standard library which is also readable by excel. The advantages of using xlwt is that you can apply formating, merge cells, formulas, and so many other features that are part of the xls file format.

```
import xlwt
from Tkinter import *            
from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename      

def callback():
    filename = askopenfilename()
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    ws0 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            ws0.write(i, 0, line.strip())
    wb.save('output.xls')

errmsg = 'Error!'
a = Button(text='click me', command=callback)
a.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Marwan Thanks for giving valuable suggession to try xlvt! but my problem actually is with running the script. Ya  i can read the file, and even print all the lines. I'm getting error " Line_Read = linecache.getline(File_Name, Loop_Counter)
NameError: global name 'linecache' is not defined" while running and linecache is already imported. please help if you have any idea about this error

Comment: You might have a problem with your python installation. Your code worked just fine with me with no errors. Try and re-install python, also try your code on another machine as a test.

Answer (score 0):

```
        import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
        root = Tkinter.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        dirname=tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')
        do something with dirname
        print dirname

#This code for file selection:

    from Tkinter import Tk
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

    Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing

    filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
    print(filename)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Yeah, now go through the code i had edited it.Code for selecting file and Code for selecting directory.